# How to redirect to Routing.prefixes pages after login?

Tags: cakephp

I'm using the [Users plugin](https://github.com/cakedc/users) to handle users.
When users want access to a normal page that requires login they are redirected to the login page, and after successful login redirected to the page. That's all good and expected.

My problem is with redirect to pages behind Routing.prefixes, where users are sent to the login page, but after successful login are redirected to the default redirect page ($this->Auth->loginRedirect).

How can I make Cake redirect to the page the user requested which is behind a Routing.prefix?
I guess it's a configuration I'm missing, or?

In config.php I have
`Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));`

Comment: To make sure we understand your question - you're asking how to have CakePHP redirect to a page with a routing prefix - ie "admin/users/myaccount" - correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

In AppController::beforeFilter this fixes it:

```
// make sure only admin can access admin area
if (isset($this->params['admin']) && $this->params['admin']) {
    if ($this->Auth->user() && !$this->Auth->user('is_admin')) {
        $this->redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override Cake's "automagic" login process.

In your app_controller.php's beforeFilter():

```
$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
```

Create an app_users_controller and override the login() function:

```
App::import('Controller', 'Users.Users');
AppUsersController extends UsersController {

    function login() {
        if(isset($this->data)) {
            if($this->Auth->login($this->data)) {
                $this->redirect(...)
            }
        }   
    }
}
```